# How to switch 2 scripts based on browser size?

Tags: scripting, php, html, javascript

I'm new here.

I'd like to ask if you can switch 2 scripts using a script? Currently, I have 2 different sizes of banners which are being called using invocation codes.

Invocation code for 728x90

```
<ins data-revive-zoneid="12" data-revive-target="_blank" data-revive-blockcampaign="1" data-revive-id="713df90a5694f87d7cd7c1884e8e2f44"></ins>
<script async src="//www.site.com/baby/delivery/asyncjs.php">
```

Invocation code for 300x50

```
<ins data-revive-zoneid="6" data-revive-id="713df90a5694f87d7cd7c1884e8e2f44"></ins>
<script async src="//www.site.com/baby/delivery/asyncjs.php"></script>
```

What I have so far is this, but haven't tried it yet.

```
if (Webbrowser)
{

728x90 Invocation code

}

if(Mobile Browser)
{

300x50 Invocation code

}
```

Basically, I just want to switch 2 invocation codes depending on the size of the browser. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Keep both implementations in separate divs. 
In the css, hide or show the divs based on the size of the screen.

HTML

```
 <div class="largebanner"> <!-- code for banner large --></div>
 <div class="smallbanner"> <!-- code for banner small --></div>
```

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
   .largebanner {
        display : block;
    }
   .smallbanner {
        display : none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
   .largebanner {
        display : none;
    }
   .smallbanner {
        display : block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm gonna try it now and give you update.

Comment: By the way, what do the min-width and max width do? I notice that they have a difference of 1 pixel only?

Comment: for display size upto 767px (max-width) use this block of css... and for display sizes of beyond 768px min-width) use this block... the limits are inclusive , hence difference of 1px

Comment: Ahh..Thank you! Is this also the size I need to put for mobile? or should I put 300 px?

Comment: Also how to put the code inside the div..do I need to include the exclamation point (!) ?

Comment: I'm having a problem here. The number of impressions will be doubled if 2 codes are placed. Is there any other way to switch them?